# Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu dual boot, can't choose windows 8.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8732930/

So I have the following setup

```
1TB Seagate HDD  -sda
1TB Samsung 850 Pro SSD -sdb
I had Three partitions on the HDD
One for OS, another for Games and last for downloads.
```

After installing the SSD I copied the games and the OS onto the SSD. Deleted these volumes in Windows from the HDD and extended the Download partition onto the whole drive.
It worked just fine. For weeks.

Now I freed up 100GB off my SSD to install ubuntu.

I partition those 100GB:

```
Ext4 - 50 GB root: /
Ext4-  42 GB Root: /home
Swap area: 16GB
```

I have run the boot repair from USB stick, and after that I now have GRUB as in I can choose which OS to run, but there is only Ubuntu and advanced for ubuntu. No windows 8.1.

I have disabled Fast boot before installing. and in the bios I tried disabling Secure boot, but there was no option for that so I set it from Windows to Other OS.

Comment: You have dynamic partitions on sda. Shown as SFS in fdisk. That does not work with Linux. Best to use third party Windows tools to undo that, Windows itself will creat dynamic but has no undo. You have BIOS based installs, so no UEFI.

Comment: that's weird because I always boot the USB with the UEFI: USB NAME

Instead of the plain USB Drive Name option.

Problem is I can't really undo that as I have no access to windows, but I can wipe that drive as it has only media data I can redownload

Comment: Some of the Windows tools are a bootable Windows repair CD. Never used this, but some have used it: http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it works now, somehow, I am not 100% sure what was the fix in the end so I am gonna go through everything.

```
First of all I installed by following the steps here:
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html
```

That included boot-repair etc.

> " So, let's try reinstall the grub-efi sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi; sudo > update-grub –  Marcos Rocha 3 hours ago " –  Marcos Rocha 3 hours ago

After trying that I got to the state where I had two options to boot into windows, One was using my HDD which makes no sense as there is nothing installed there anymore but whatever probably a relic left behind from HDD cloning to SSD.

```
1. Create a Win764bit usb 
2. Boot onto USB
3. Run startup repair 
4. -> AFter restart it still didn't work I updated grub2 with something like :
```

> sudo apt-get reinstall grub2
>
> sudo update-grub2

**IRRELEVANT FROM HERE**

Then in BIOS of my ASUS H87M-E

I set back the boot option to WINDOWS from OTHER OS.

One of these solved it.

```
Edit: Went ahead and switched it back from WINDOWS UEFI mode to Other OS.
Still works.
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced out the same issue 2 months ago. These following questions help me so much.

[Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 8 - no operating system found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403692/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-8-no-operating-system-found?rq=1)

and

[Restore backup of WinEFI or UEFI (not sure) that boot-repair made](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377252/restore-backup-of-winefi-or-uefi-not-sure-that-boot-repair-made/377288#377288)

Good luck.

Comment: these only point me to wiping the whole stuff and setting it up again, but maybe with Windows 7 this time as atleast that's not such a pain in the butt.

I would like to avoid that, and try to fix it somehow.

Comment: So, let's try reinstall the grub-efi `sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi`; `sudo update-grub`

Comment: kamee@kamee-ubuntu:~$ sudo update-grub 

Generating grub configuration file ... 

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic 

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-39-generic 

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic 

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda3. 

Check your device.map. 

Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1 

Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sdb1 

now the /dev/sda1 part is obviously bullcrap and doest work.

The /dev/sdb1 part says missing bootmgr if try to boot it

Comment: Is the secure boot enabled on BIOS?

Comment: solved it, poster the answer too.

Comment: Congratulations!!! Your experience will be useful for others.